# Word that means every outcome is worse?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What word means that every outcome is worse than where you started,

For example, You must make a choice but the choices are a worse situation than your current one.

Comment: In chess this is referred to by the German term *Zugzwang*.

Comment: You might consider [Nash Equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium).

Comment: @Robusto does Zugzwang means **tight spot.**

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but perhaps *unenviable* choice would work for you? To my mind, it implies a choice in which every option has serious negative consequences

Comment: ' You must make a choice but the choices are a worse situation than your current one.' Do the choices include 'do nothing'? I don't see how this can apply.

Answer (score 2):

This might be described as a "*no-win situation*"—a situation where there are multiple possible outcomes, but none of them are seen as positive.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation):

> A no-win situation, also called a “lose-lose situation”, is one where a person has choices, but no choice leads to a net gain.

Or from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/no-win-situation):

> A situation certain to end in failure or disappointment, as in *If the in-laws visit them or they visit the in-laws, either way they see it as a no-win situation*. [c. 1960]

Comment: Thank you, I read an article that made reference of this word, it is not a saying but a singular word, any ideas?

Comment: @goodquestionmma Could you [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/491733/edit) your question to include a an example of how you'd use the word in a sentence? Also, be sure to include the `single-word-request` tag to clarify to other users that a single word is preferred over a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom for this (at least in the case where you can see that one choice is not as bad as all the others) is [least-worst](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/least-worst):

> the least worst choice is the best choice from a list of choices that you think are all bad

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the word **irresultive.** It does not exactly mean, every outcome is a worse outcome, but it means, ***your outcome/result is furitless*** e.g. in chess, if you are facing a situation where, if you take any permitted permuted move, then those all probable moves will not yield any (favorable) results. So, normally you will say- "All moves are fruitless".

Merriam Webster dictionary defines *[irresultive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irresultive)* as:

> lacking result : **ABORTIVE**

*[Abortive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abortive)* according to Merriam Webster dictionary is,

> FRUITLESS, UNSUCCESSFUL

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/irresultive) also backs *irresultive* as:

> **Useless** or  **without result** or **done in vain**.

---

Also, **lose-lose** is defined as adjective in oxford dictionary.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lose-lose)

> Of or denoting a situation which is disadvantageous or damaging to all those involved.
>
> > "Is it worth arguing in this lose-lose situation?"